# ssh port forwarding требует пароль

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

Пытаюсь настроит ssh port forwarding так: 
`ssh -fN -l root -L 127.0.0.1:5900:localhost:5900 server_ip`
После этого терминал запрашивает root@ip password:
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Но мой хостер требует подключаться через ssh ключи и не позволяет задавать пароль. Как быть?

Comment: убрать `-l root` из команды?

Comment: Не помогло, все равно требует пароль рута.

Comment: а может быть Вы от рута залогинены на своей машине? разберитесь, каким пользователем нужно подключаться к серверу и укажите его в парамертре `-l`.

Comment: Вы точно прочитали документацию на `ssh` в главе, где разъясняется механизм проброса портов?

Comment: 1. *запрашивает пароль рута* — приведите **полный** текст того, что получаете в терминале (добавьте это прямо в текст вопроса, нажав [edit]). 2. при выполнении команды `$ ssh root@server_ip` вы получаете **точно такой же** запрос пароля?

Comment: Да, точно такой же: root@ip password: Permission denied (publickey,password).